# Model do POST chegando null na controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema complicado no meu código que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Inicialmente, eu tenho uma função `SubmitUsuarioRegistro` do *JavaScript* que realiza o post do perfil do usuário, encaminhando as informações para a `controller`.
Este código estava funcionando normalmente:

```
function SubmitUsuarioRegistro() {
    var _queryString = $(#form-usuario).find('input, select').serialize();
    $.post('/Usuario/SalvarUsuarioPerfil', { objModel: _queryString }, function (resultado) {
        UsuarioPerfilSalvoValidacao(resultado);
    }).fail(function (ex) {
        notify('Não foi possível salvar seu perfil, entre em contato conosco!', 'danger');        
    });
}
```

E esta é minha `controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SalvarUsuarioPerfil(UsuarioViewModel objModel)
{
    bool _bSucesso = false;
    int _idPk = 0;
    string xMsg = string.Empty;            

    //Template de salvar usuário.
    //Usado para separar as funcionalidades dentro da controller.            
    _cudTemplate = new SalvarUsuarioPerfilTemplate();
    try
    {
        var objInformacoesUser = UsuarioHelper.BuscaInformacoesUsuarioSession();
        var _retornoAux = _cudTemplate.SalvarUsuarioPerfil(objModel, objInformacoesUser.idAspNetUser, objInformacoesUser.idEmpresa);
        _bSucesso = _retornoAux.bSucesso;
        _idPk = _retornoAux.idRetorno;
        xMsg = _retornoAux.xMensagemRetorno;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("NaoAutorizado", "Account", new { xMensagemValidacao = ex.Message.ToString() });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.ToString().Contains("login"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NaoAutorizado", "Account", new { xMensagemValidacao = ex.Message.ToString() });
        }

        xMsg = ex.Message.ToString();
    }


    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = new
        {
            result = _bSucesso,
            mensagem = xMsg,
            primaryKey = _idPk
        },
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

Após eu ter dado o update do visual studio (realmente não sei se isso tem relação ou não), o POST começou  a vir `null` na `controller`.
Dentro do *JavaScript* ele faz todo o processo de *serialize* corretamente, mas ao chegar na `controller` chega `null`.

Eu realmente não sei como resolver, 
alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Essa requisição está chegando no Controller?

Comment: Chega sim, ele também faz o serialize com todos os campos corretamente, só que vem nulo

Comment: Certamento o seu problema esteja no tipo de dado passado para sua action. ela espera um SalvarUsuarioPerfil(UsuarioViewModel objModel) e você esta mandando um objeto  var _queryString. isso é compartível ? existe outras formas de usar o jquery para fazer chamada na action mais intuitivas que a que você esta usando. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25068499/2740371

Comment: Então, eu estava passando o nome da modelagem nele, porém, quando eu retirei o nome e passei apenas _queryString, deu certo, como deixei na minha resposta. Mas até o momento não entendi o motivo, pois estava funcionando e de uma hora pra outra parou.

Answer (score 1):

Eu realizei alguns procedimentos:

-Tentei utilizar um $.param que vi através desse post [Post sem form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form)

Esse acima, que aparentemente seria uma correção, não me ajudou no problema.

O que **corrigiu esse problema**  foi simplismente retirar o nome da model que eu passava no $.post

```
 $.post('/Usuario/SalvarUsuarioPerfil', _queryString , function (resultado)
```

Eu marquei como resposta porque resolveu meu problema, porém não entendi o motivo desse comportamento entre a view e a controller. Se alguém tiver alguma opinião sobre, vou deixar em aberto durante a semana e finalizo esse post.